# <a colloquial expression> and all that / and (all) that / and all (that)

Tags: idioms

Happy New Year.

Indeed, I have learned "and all that" / "and (all) that".

[<and all? or all but?> Well, the thing is he is really attractive and all but he is not funny. I hate it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270787/and-all-or-all-but-well-the-thing-is-he-is-really-attractive-and-all-but-he?noredirect=1#comment505065_270787)

My question No.1: I am curious whether "and all (that)" could be also used.

My questions No.2: could I take the meaning "and all that" / "and (all) that" /"and all (that)" as the below one?

[What does "... and all" means?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16011/what-does-and-all-means)

> and all is a colloquial expression—do not use it in formal contexts. It means, approximately, “and everything else that is associated with that”. It is used at the end of a clause, and it is dismissive: it characterizes what that clause says or implies as unimportant or unimpressive. It is almost always followed immediately by a clause (usually headed by but) which expresses what the speaker regards as, in contrast, more important or impressive.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is exactly as in the linked question.  "He is attractive" (but I dismiss this fact as not important because) "He is not funny".   Do you think that question duplicates this one, or is there something different?

Comment: Above all, thank you so much for your feeback.Because I have looked up other usages of and all as well in my previous question. Perhaps you think it would be duplicate, though. Also I was able to get something meaningful while talking with FumbleFingersReinstateMonica.

Comment: _...And all that_ is the usual colloquial expression. _And all_ or _and that_ are even more informal variants.

Comment: @KateBunting Always thank you for teaching!